# Snapping vertices (Ctrl + Click) not working

Tags: modeling

I'm creating clothes and having some troubles
[image]

I created a vertice using ctrl + click, it seems to be perfectly ontop of the other mesh I am using. Now when I try to create another vertice:
[image]

It goes straight through. Is there any way to stop it and actually have the edge not going through my mesh? 
I am able to not let it through but this is only if I use a lot of vertices which shouldn't be the solution considering in other tutorials they do it the same way as I did.

Comment: I don't see where the problem is. Both vertices are on the surface of the mesh. Edge connecting them is mostly inside due to lack of geometry, i.e. it's too long straight line and mesh surface becomes round much quicker than edge can follow it

Comment: Thanks, something I notice too is that my normals are flipped to the wrong side, any way to stop themf rom doing that?

Comment: Are you certain it's normal? When I tried using edges instead of vertices it did the same: https://i.imgur.com/zuVHWJJ.png

Comment: There isn't any way to stop faces normals facing the wrong side, it's much easier and flexible to recalculate them (Ctrl+N), i.e. fix this afterwards. I've no idea what do you mean by "using vertices instead of edges", the fewer geometry the shrinkwrapped surface has the more it will be falling into the highpoly - it can't follow curvature of the highpoly, that one is too smooth, lowpoly is too steep. The more geometry you have for lowpoly, the fewer that effect will be visible (and less sense in doing lowpoly).